# How to get rid of the "Uncaught TypeError: feof(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource" logged error?

Tags: php, try-catch, typeerror, fsockopen, feof

For years now, I've been trying to solve this insanely annoying issue. Seemingly at random, my fsockopen-using code fails and PHP-logs the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: feof(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource

For the `if (feof($the_connection))` line.

Normally, it works. This only happens "sometimes", *presumably* when there's a temporary network issue or a proxy is temporarily unavailable or something like that.

I've tried to use `@` to suppress it. Doesn't work. I've tried looking in the manual for `feof` to see if it has some parameter to turn this off. It doesn't.

In desperation, I've even tried wrapping it inside a `try...catch` block to make it shut up. It doesn't help:

```
try
{
    if (feof($the_connection))
        return false;
}
catch (exception $e)
{
    return false;
}
```

No matter what I do, the damn "TypeError" sometimes happens and is logged, frustrating me since my code isn't "rock solid" to handle this case.

Online, there's *no reference at all to this error*, which is very unusual.

How do I make it stop? What can I possibly need to do since I actually do "try" and "catch"?